# About the Identity function in Agda

Tags: dependent-types

I've defined the identity function in `Agda` as follows:

```
idd : (∀ {ℓ} {A: Set ℓ}) → A → A
idd a = a
```

I want to ask you if the following reasonings are correct:

- The type of this function is `A -> A`.
- `idd` is a polymorphic function, where `(∀ {ℓ} {A: Set ℓ})` matches any type.
- Because is a polymorphic function, I can say `idd` is of dependent type.

Comment: What do you mean "well-defined"?  Does Agda accept it? If so, isn't that evidence enough? If not, that would seem more compelling than anything we could say.

Comment: I've modified the question.

Comment: As the code you provided doesn't parse, at least in Agda 2.4.2.5, I suspect that isn't how you defined the function in Agda.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code does not work. I would suggest that you forget about the universe levels for the time being (the $\ell$ thing) and focus on simpler things first. Here is working code:

```
idd : (A : Set) → A → A
idd A a = a
```

The type of `idd` is `(A : Set) → A → A`. It is a dependent product, i.e., it could be written as $\prod_{A : \mathsf{Set}} A \to A$ in mathematical notation. If we have a type `B` then the type of `id B` is `B → B`.

You say:

> The type of this function is `A -> A`.

No. The type if `idd` is exactly what it says, namely `(A : Set) → A → A`.

> `idd` is a polymorphic function, where (∀ {ℓ} {A: Set ℓ}) matches any type.

Let us forget about `ℓ`. In this case the question is whether `idd` is a polymorphic function. The answer is "yes" because `A` matches any type.

> Because is a polymorphic function, I can say idd is of dependent type.

No. This is the wrong way to think. The function `idd` does *not* have a dependent type. It has the *fixed* type `(A : Set) → A → A`. However, this fixed type is a *dependent product*.

Comment: I am confused about how the identity function is not a dependent type because I see it depends on a term that in this case is A, a term of Set

Comment: The term `A` in the type `(A : Set) → A → A` is a **bound variable** and does not really exist. If you say you see an `A` then I will say that there is no `A` in `(B : Set) → B → B`. The types `(A : Set) → A → A` and `(B : Set) → B → B` are *equal*. It is just silly notation that makes you think there is an `A` in there. The type of `idd` is *not* dependent, but it is a dependent product. Assuming `X` is a variable of type `Set`, the type of `idd X` *is* dependent. It depends on `X`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the following code for answer your questions:

```
idd : (A : Set) → A → A
idd A a = a
```

Is `idd` a polymorphic function? No. Agda (without universe polymorphism) is a monomorphic language. The `idd` function is only defined on small types, i.e. `Set`. The function is not defined on `Set1`, `Set2`, ...

Has `idd` a dependent type? Yes. I'll quote Bove and Dybjer [2009, p. 64]:

> Here we see a first use of dependent types: the type `A -> A` depends on the
>   variable `A : Set` ranging over the small types.

Bove, A. and Dybjer, P. (2009). Dependent Types at Work. In: LerNet ALFA Summer School 2008. Ed. by Bove, A., Soares Barbosa, L., Pardo, A. and Sousa Pinto, J. Vol. 5520. Lecture Notes in Computer Science. Springer, pp. 57–99.